# Why doesnt Pythons += (plus equals) operator modify variables from inner functions?

Tags: python, list, scope

I would like to know details about why this doesn't work as expected:

```
def outer():
    mylist = []
    def inner():
        mylist += [1]

    inner()

outer()
```

Especially because `mylist.__iadd__([1])` works fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't use `.extend()`?

Comment: or `.append()`, if you're just adding one value.

Comment: Those are specific to lists, there are general solutions to the problem.

Comment: Every single day someone comes with an `UnboundLocalError`...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that when you assign to a variable name inside a function, Python assumes you're trying to create a new local variable that will mask a similarly-named variable in outer scope. Since `+=` has to *get* the value of `mylist` before it can modify it, it complains, because the local version of `mylist` isn't yet defined. [MRAB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797164/why-doesnt-pythons-plus-equals-operator-modify-variables-from-inner-function/6797210#6797210) gives a clear explanation of the semantics.

On the other hand, when you do `mylist.__iadd__([1])`, you aren't assigning a new variable name inside the function. You're just using a built-in method to modify an already-assigned variable name. As long as you don't try to assign a new value to `mylist`, you won't have a problem. For the same reason, the line `mylist[0] = 5` would also work inside `inner` if the definition of `mylist` in `outer` were `mylist = [1]`.

Note however that if you do try to assign a new value to `mylist` anywhere in the function, `mylist.__iadd__([1])` will indeed fail:

```
>>> outer()
>>> def outer():
...     mylist = []
...     def inner():
...         mylist.__iadd__([1])
...         mylist = []
...     inner()
... 
>>> outer()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in outer
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in inner
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mylist' referenced before assignment
```

If you want to assign a new value to a variable from a containing scope, in 3.0+ you can use `nonlocal`, in just the way you'd use `global` to assign a new value to a variable in global scope. So instead of this:

```
>>> mylist = []
>>> def inner():
...     global mylist
...     mylist += [1]
... 
>>> inner()
>>> mylist
[1]
```

You do this:

```
def outer():
    mylist = []
    def inner():
        nonlocal mylist
        mylist += [1]
    inner()
    print(mylist)
outer()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very detailed. I did not know that Python tries `x = x.__iadd__(y)` (thanks @MRAB) and assumed it would just do `x.__iadd__(y)`. I also finall renamed the variable ;)

Answer (score 6):

If a name is bound (a variable is assigned) in a function then that name is treated as local unless it's declared global.

Thus in `inner`, `mylist` is local.

When you write `x += y`, at runtime Python will try:

```
x = x.__iadd__(y)
```

If that fails, Python then tries:

```
x = x.__add__(y)
```

Comment: +1, the specific semantics are useful here. This also shows that `__iadd__` both modifies the object to which it is bound _and_ returns the result of that modification. You won't see many "public" built-in methods do that.

Answer (score 1):

Any variable assigned to is assumed to be of local scope.

To assign to a global variable you do:

```
global var
var = 5
```

You can't do quite what you're doing in Python 2, but in Python 3 you can do:

```
nonlocal mylist
mylist += [1]
```

The Python 2 alternative for changing an item or attribute of something is

```
def outer():
    mylist = []
    def inner(mylist = mylist):
        mylist += [1]
    inner()
outer()
```

If you want to replace the value of the variable, you need to:

```
def outer():
    def setlist(newlist):
        mylist = newlist
    mylist = []
    def inner():
        setlist(['new_list'])
    inner()
outer()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `myList` inside `inner()` does not refer to `myList` defined in `outer()`, and thats why the plus equals operator does not work. There are two solutions that come to my mind.

The first, would be passing `myList` to inner as an argument:

```
def outer():
    mylist = []
    def inner(someList):
        somelist += [1]

    inner(mylist)

outer()
```

The second solution is to declare myList outside both functions, and then declaring it as `global` inside both functions:

```
mylist = []
def outer():
    global mylist
    mylist = []
    def inner():
        global mylist
        mylist += [1]

    inner()

outer()
```

Though I would recommend the first solution.

Comment: but I do not really think that his problem revolves around closure.